# how to display mysql GROUP_CONCAT values in php without while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `profile` like this

```
S/N   Name   Age (VALUES) (1, Julius, 5 ) (2, Mark, 7) (3, Ismael, 9)
```

I want to display a result that will fetch the name row and separate the values with comma, e.g.

```
$result = Julius, Mark, Isamel
```

I used

```
$resuk = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name) FROM profile;");
      $get_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resuk); 
 $values = explode(",", $get_info);
       echo $values;
```

This gave me below error

```
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dowel\commasep.php on line
```

I would appreciate if someone can assist.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> mysqli_fetch_assoc() function fetches a result row as an associative
> array.

So your `$get_info` variable is basically a whole row, you need to explode the FIELD and NOT the whole ROW

You should be able to achieve this by assigning a column alias from your query result like so

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name) as AllNames FROM profile;");
```

And then you can access that column in the explode function like so

```
$values = explode(",", $get_info['AllNames']);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @slashroot. Your response shed more light on my issues and i was able to finally resolve it even without the explode.

$resuk = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name)  as AllNames FROM profile;");
     $get_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resuk); 
     $result = $get_info['AllNames'];
     echo $result ;
     $result = Julius, Mark, Isamel
    
Thanks a million